# Does Python subprocess allow for executing shell variables from within the Python file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, path, pathlib

I have some source. In the source, I need to use shell variables to promote changing a couple GPIO pins to input during the python script.

The GPIO pins are output by default and I would only like them to be input during specific intervals of the source...

Is this possible with python alone or should using shell variables make it easier?

For instance...I use:

```
from pathlib import Path
from time import sleep

Sense = Path('/sys/class/gpio/gpio60/value')

sense.write_text('low')
sleep(1)
sense.write_text('high')
sleep(2)
```

This will use the GPIO pin in question as output and then make it off for one second and then on for two seconds before stopping the sequence of events.

Is there a way w/ pathlib.Path to make the output an input?